# iOS app → Safari with a certain webpage → Some action on a webpage → Back to an app with some data?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to send an iOS app user to a certain webpage in Safari and then have a user back in an app, after one has done some action on a webpage?

Comment: If the webpage has a callback to the app — sure why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

From the Web, you have to link to an URL scheme registered to your App, for example, register your app with the "myownurlscheme", and you can start adding links and redirects in your Web, example:

myownurlscheme://goto/restaurant/drink&what=beer

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Beginning with iOS 9, there's now Universal Linking.

So when a user visits your site, iOS automatically pushes you to the App (and the App receives the full URL), if the users doesn't have the App, keeps seeing the Web version.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12